# Android In-app Promotions: The code you entered is invalid

Tags: android, in-app-promotions

I am implementing Android [In-app Promotions](https://developer.android.com/intl/zh-tw/google/play/billing/billing_promotions.html), and when I enter the promo code from market I get this message:

> The code you entered is invalid

Can someone post a short tutorial about how to implement and test **In-app Promotions**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just learned that I've been doing them wrong. I made up a name for my promo, e.g. "appliv" and thought that was the promo code. It turns out that you need to go to the promo and look for a line like this:

```
Number of promo codes       5 codes download
```

Click on the "d̲o̲w̲n̲l̲o̲a̲d̲" link to receive your promo codes. They're long sequences of quasi-random characters and each can only be used once.

Any chance this was your problem? Took me forever to figure it out.

Comment: My problem exactly, this is really not intuitive usage of promo codes.

Comment: Took me over a month, and multiple complaints from people I was trying to give the promo codes, before I finally figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

Just sharing my experience on this topic...
A promotion code has a limited time window during which it is active. If you try to consume the code while it's not active it will fail.

Also, the promotion may take some time to propagate to other Google servers, which may explain why you get an error.

Wait for a few minutes and try again.